# Hold down button in golang fyne

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

With the fyne GUI framework it's easy to build simple guis with basic functionality.
I was unable to find a way to detect the user pushing and holding a button for some time. I can only detect wether the button was clicked. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets in fyne come with their most likely used functionality. When a widget does not offer a functionality, that is needed, it can be extended. [An example where an icon is made clickable can be seen here.](https://developer.fyne.io/extend/extending-widgets) In this example the interface fyne/v2.Tappable is being implemented, which also contains an icon, which leads to a clickable icon.

To make a button holdable we need to implement an interface, which can register mousedown and mouseup events. This interface is fyne/v2/driver/desktop.Mouseable.

So this is what this can look like:

```golang
package main
import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/driver/desktop"
    "log"
)

type holdableButton struct {
    widget.Button
}
func newHoldableButton(label string) *holdableButton {
    button := &holdableButton{}
    button.ExtendBaseWidget(button)
    button.Text=label
    return button
}

func (h *holdableButton) MouseDown(*desktop.MouseEvent){
    log.Println("down")
}
func (h *holdableButton) MouseUp(*desktop.MouseEvent){
    log.Println("up")
}

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Holdable")
    w.SetContent(newHoldableButton("Button"))
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Important to note: The Mouseable interface does not appear by name and the driver package only needs to be imported to reference the desktop.MouseEvent. But as is the case in golang the interface is implemented by creating the two methods MouseUp and MouseDown and both need to exist even if you only "need" one, otherwise none of this will work.

Thank you to andy.xyz who pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yea it is. The button widget doesn’t provide it as that’s not part of button actions.
However any widget can be extended to listen to the lower level mouse (desktop) or touch (mobile) events.
You can find the interfaces in driver/desktop/ and driver/mobile/ packages.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried to look into it, but I am having trouble to understand how to do it. Can you give me an example on how to extend a widget using the fyne drivers?

Comment: Extending docs are at https://developer.fyne.io/extend/extending-widgets - then you just need the appropriate interface implementation for the driver event you want (which are in the driver packages).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I found that doc as well, but my problem ist, they extend it based on an interface (Tappable), that is defined in the "fyne/v2" package, but there is no like "Holdable" interface there. You speak of the "fyne/v2/driver/desktop" package I believe and what I found there is the Canvas interface, which has OnKeyDown and so on. Sounds good, but I was unable to implement that interface to use as an extension. Is that what you mean? Or is it the Mousable interface? I kinda feel lost here.

Comment: Yes if you want to know if a mouse button was held down use the Mouseable interface which will tell you when the button is pressed and released.

Comment: Thank you, I have created an answer to my question, which I would not have been able to do without your aid.